# JQuery Box-shadow inset problem

Tags: jquery, css

I have a problem with JQuery and inset Box-Shadow.

First of all I have a input field.

```
<input id="name" name="name" type="text" />
```

That field has the following css styles:

```
 #contact input[type="text"] {
     background: rgba(55,55,55, 0.6);
     height:2em;
     border: 1px dashed #666;
     width:200px;
     box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 10px #222;
     border-radius: 2px;
}
```

Okay. Now the JQuery part:

What I want to do! If I hover over my input field i want an "outer" box-shadow. Like: boxShadow: "0px 0px 15px #750082". But the inset box-shadow should be the same!!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#message").hover(
        function()
            {$(this).stop().animate({boxShadow: "0px 0px 15px #750082"},800);
            },
        function()
            {$(this).stop().animate({boxShadow: "inset 0px 0px 10px #222222"});

    });
});
```

The problem is that the "outer" box shadow will be displayed as an inset box-shadow.
But I want an "outer" box-shadow and a inset box-shadow!

So whats wrong with my solution? Has someone a better one?

Best regards

*edit*
I'm using JQuery 1.6.2, for the boxshadow I'm using http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/shadow-animation/test.html Plugin!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here are *two* options to get the same desired result

[example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/aCmUH/)

**1: Use a wrapper for the `<input>`**

```
<span id="nameWrapper">
    <input id="name" name="name" type="text" value="" />
</span>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#name").hover(function() {
    $(this).parent().stop().animate({
        boxShadow: "0px 0px 15px #750082"
    }, 800);
}, function() {
    $(this).parent().stop().animate({
        boxShadow: ""
    }, 800);
});
```

**2: Use CSS3 transitions instead**

CSS:

```
#contact input[type="text"] {
    background: rgba(55,55,55, 0.6);
    height:2em;
    border: 1px dashed #666;
    width:200px;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 10px #222;
    border-radius: 2px;
    outline:0;/* prevent webkit highlight on focus */
    -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
       -moz-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
         -o-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
            transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
}
#contact input[type="text"]:hover {
    /* set both shadows */
    box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 10px #222,0px 0px 15px #750082;
}
```

you may consider writing the author of the shadow plugin to notify him/her of this issue.

Comment: yep, question is about `box-shadow` which is also [not supported in IE8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh781508(v=vs.85).aspx)